# What is python "RAII" idiom for a variable number of resources?

Tags: python, file, variables, resources, raii

What is the "best" way to open a variable number of files in python?

I can't fathom how to use "with" if the number of files is not known before-hand.

(Incoming from RAII/C++)

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071121/raii-in-python-automatic-destruction-when-leaving-a-scope

Comment: I can't fathom what "the number of files is not known before-hand" can possibly mean.  Can you provide an explanation for this algorithm which opens (and keeps open) an unknown number of files.

Comment: Example: a script that takes a variable number of filenames on the command-line and interleaves them all line-by-line to stdout .

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could define your own context manager that took a list of `(filename, mode)` pairs and returned a list of open file handles (and then closed all of those handles when the contextmanager exits).

See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers and http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html for more details on how to define your own context managers.

Comment: This fits the bill perfectly.

Comment: After your clear description and a re-read of the context-manager docs this seems very obvious to me - now. So thanks for being gentle with a newbie!

Comment: If this answer met your needs, please mark it as accepted by clicking the outline of a checkmark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With 3.3, `contextlib.ExitStack` is now available for situations such as this.  Here's some example code from the `contextlib` documentation:

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
    # All opened files will automatically be closed at the end of
    # the with statement, even if attempts to open files later
    # in the list raise an exception
```

2.7 users are out of luck.  Yet another reason to upgrade.