# Case when __del__ will not be called at the end of application

Tags: python-2.7, garbage-collection

Class `CumulativeSender` is sending email at the end of aplication. I read about problems with garbage collector and `__del__` and I would like to know if there is case when `__del__` for `staticCumulativeSenderObject` will not be called at the end of application and why?

CumulativeSender.py:

```
import smtplib;

_staticCumulativeSenderObject = None;


class CumulativeSender(object):

    def __init__(self):

        recipients['sender'] = 'from@domain.com';
        recipients['emails'] = ['to@domain.com'];
        recipients['subject'] = 'Test Email';
        recipients['smtp_host'] = 'localhost';

        self.message = "";
        self.fromaddr = recipients['sender'];
        self.toaddrs  = recipients['emails'];
        self.subject = recipients['subject'];

        self.server = smtplib.SMTP(recipients['smtp_host']);

    def __del__(self):
        if(self.message):
            msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n" % (self.fromaddr, ", ".join(self.toaddrs))) + "Subject: " + self.subject + "\r\n\r\n" + self.message;
            self.server.sendmail(self.fromaddr, self.toaddrs, msg);
        self.server.quit();

    def immediateSend():
        global _staticCumulativeSenderObject;
        if(_staticCumulativeSenderObject is not None):
            toDelete = _staticCumulativeSenderObject;
            _staticCumulativeSenderObject = None;
            del toDelete;


    immediateSend = staticmethod(immediateSend);


    def addEvent(msg):
        global _staticCumulativeSenderObject;
        if(_staticCumulativeSenderObject is None):
            _staticCumulativeSenderObject = CumulativeSender();
        _staticCumulativeSenderObject.message += msg + "\r\n";

    addEvent = staticmethod(addEvent);


    def addAlert(msg, code = None):
        CumulativeSender.addEvent(buildMessage("Allert",msg,code));

    addAlert = staticmethod(addAlert);


    def addError(msg, code = None):
        CumulativeSender.addEvent(buildMessage("Error",msg,code));

    addError = staticmethod(addError);
```

simple use:

```
import CumulativeSender;
CumulativeSender.CumulativeSender.addAlert("alert1", 345);
CumulativeSender.CumulativeSender.addAlert("alert2", 346);
```

Or maybe there is another way to do what I want?

Comment: Don't override `__del__` unless you have a very good reason. If you're not sure, you don't.

Comment: Please propose something that will replace `__del__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should never relay on `__del__`. But your question is „when `__del__` method will not be called?”. That actually is simply, whenever you have a circular references that point to your object. In that case Python cannot distinguish which object should be deleted first, so Python won't call any `__del__` method at all. The harder question is when you actually can get a circular reference, but that will not solve you problem.

The wrong use of `__del__` method usually come from [trying to use RAII technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071121/raii-in-python-automatic-destruction-when-leaving-a-scope).

Well you code will run well until some one make a reference to `_staticCumulativeSenderObject` from a object involved in circular reference. But even if it looks like a private and no one should make any references, it is a bad design. This code will do exactly what `atexit` module is for.

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def _sendAtExit():
    global _staticCumulativeSenderObject
    if _staticCumulativeSenderObject:
         #do what your __del__ is doing
        _staticCumulativeSenderObject.send_and_close()
        _staticCumulativeSenderObject=None
```

Comment: Thx for answer different from "`__del__` is devil" and for providing me something that I can use instead of `__del__`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a really good reason to override `__del__`. In the vast majority of the cases the disadvantages outweigh the advantages. You can find plenty of reading about `__del__` using a websearch engine of your choice.

You didn't explain why you prefer an implicit approach, rather than adding a `send()` method and calling it explicitly when you want to send the email.  That would be my ultimate suggestion.

However, trusting that you do have a good reason for the implicit approach, you can define a [context manager](http://eigenhombre.com/2013/04/20/introduction-to-context-managers/), by defining `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods (or by using the [contextlib.contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) shortcut). Usage would be something like:

```
with CumulativeSender(...) as sender:
    sender.addEvent(...)
    sender.add...(...)
    sender.add...(...)
```

When exiting this block, the `__exit__` method is called. You can send the email there.

Note that `__exit__` is also called if an exception leaves that block, so you should decide weather or not you want to send if an exception is raised (probably not).

But again, [explicit is better than implicit](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Static methods of this class (`addAlert` and `addError`) will be used in many different places in code (different files different classes) but there is more then one entry point (many application). I can't guarantee that someone will call `send()` at the end of his application. Class user don't realy use class objects only static methods of class. There is realy no implicite for him. He use that methods and buffer is flushed at the end of application. And next line from Zen:  Simple is better than complex

Comment: @Logman What does your `main()` function look like? why can't you explicitly call `send()` as the last line of `main`? Also, in this context, what do you consider "simple" and "complex".

Comment: There is multiple main function it's not a single application. Look at this class more like module to more complex system.

Comment: When I use function(something) it's really simple, but when I need to manage some object by myself it's more complex.