# Flattening `with` and `try/finally` in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider following code:

```
async with app:
    ...
    async with app.resource as rsrc:
        ...
        async with rsrc.foo as bar:
            ...
```

Having lots of nested `with` or `async with` statements has negative effect on readability of code, especially in tests, where the same clause might be reused lots of times.

In languages like D, there is `scope(exit) ...` construct, which allows you to append code to the list of scope finalizers — this code would be executed once the scope is left, allowing you to effectively do what `__exit__` does, but without adding an indent.

Is there a way to flatten `with` in Python and do something like this?

```
await async_with(app)
scope_exit(app.quit)

...

rsrc = await async_with(app.resource)
scope_exit(rsrc.release)

...

bar = await async_with(rsrc.foo)
scope_exit(lambda: bar.unfrob())

...
```

Or, alternatively, is there a way to reliably execute arbitrary code on exiting the scope?

Comment: The [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) can have many members. I'm unsure if you can use any of the resulting variables in the statement.

Comment: @Kendas, while it's possible to include multiple clauses in single `with` statement, it's impossible to execute any code in between without resorting to `with` (or non-existent `scope_exit`)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't achieve what you want. Especially because there's no possibility to define such "scope".

Even in your pseudo-code:

```
await async_with(app)
scope_exit(app.quit)

...

rsrc = await async_with(app.resource)
scope_exit(rsrc.release)

...

bar = await async_with(rsrc.foo)
scope_exit(lambda: bar.unfrob())

raise ExceptionHere()
```

What context should [not] catch it?

I may be wrong, but the the only way to set the "guard" for catching exceptions is `try/except` clause. `with` is roughly a wrapper around it.

Speaking about motivation, if you have problems with nested context managers so hard, you should probably refactor your core to extract inner context as functions. You may take a look at [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) for helpers

Comment: If you raise an exception at the very end, it should follow the same unwinding flow like it would with nested `with` - e.g. `bar.unfrob()` should be called, then `rsrc.release()`, then `app.quit()`. If exception was raised before `scope_exit(lambda: bar.unfrob())`, then there would be no such scope finalizer, so only `rsrc.release()` and `app.quit()` should be called.

Comment: maybe I should even make this into a PEP to define the concept of "scope finalizer", to enable explicit RAII in Python.

Comment: Tbh, i really doubt the possibility of flattening such thing, but you can always try :)

I recommend following readings:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0310/ (actually, father of `with`, afaik)
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ (intuition for `with`)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071376/2161778 (RAII in python and thoughts)

Answer (score 0):

I can't stand the extra indentations from the `with` statement... This is what I do to flatten them:

Nested:

```
def stuff_with_files(path_a, path_b):
    # ... do stuff
    with open(path_a) as fileA:
        # ... do stuff with fileA
        with open(path_b) as fileB:
            # ... do stuff with fileA and fileB

def main():
    stuff_with_files('fileA.txt', 'fileB.txt')
```

Flattened:

```
# Extract the 'with' statement.
def with_file(path, func, *args, **kwargs):
    with open(path) as file:
        func(file, *args, **kwargs)


def process_a_b(fileB, results_of_a):
    # ... do stuff with fileB and results_of_a.


def process_a(fileA):
    # ... do stuff with fileA
    results = # ...
    with_file('fileB.txt', process_a_b, results)


def main():
    with_file('fileA.txt', process_a)
```